# How to start with Edge webdriver with python 2.7 and Robot framework 2.9

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, microsoft-edge

I have downloaded and installed edge webdriver from Microsoft website. I see the Edge driver folder in the "**C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium-2.48.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\edge**".

Whenever I try to execute the below Robot Test case:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation       Test Edge Browser

*** Test Case ***
Test Edge browser
    open browser    http://www.google.in    Edge
```

Though I have set the environment path for "Mircrosoftwebdriver.exe". I see the "*WebDriverException: Message: The EdgeDriver executable needs to be available in the path. Please download from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=619687*"

Please let me know if anyone has the same issue and resolved.

Comment: Did you do what the error message is telling you to do?

Comment: Have you confirmed the environmental path contains the WebDriver directory? If so, have you also closed all command windows, and tried again?

Comment: @Sampson Yes I have updated environment path with web driver directory. I have also tried by restarting pc after updating path.

Comment: @BryanOakley Even after placing the webdriver i am getting the same error message.

Comment: you can make it so you can start edge with the webdriver.  However, it is quite pointless as a number of the simplest actions have not been written yet.  Quite simply this will not work in test runs until further updates are made to Selenium2Library as Clayton mentioned below

Answer (score 3):

It looks like RobotFramework uses their own library called Selenium2Library. This library currently has a pull request to add Microsoft Edge support sitting in code review which can be found here:

https://github.com/robotframework/Selenium2Library/pull/568

Since it uses Selenium2Library the fact that selenium has support for Microsoft Edge doesn't matter. Here is where you can see supported browsers:

http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Open%20Browser

Answer (score 1):

From the (current) [Selenium2Library documentation](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html) it is clear that edge is supported.

The error provided seems to me that the executable `Mircrosoftwebdriver.exe` can not be found. The easiest way to check this is to open a command prompt (`win key`, type `cmd`, first option). In the command box type or copy-paste `Mircrosoftwebdriver.exe` and press enter. In case you get the following message, then the executable isn't in the path.

```
C:\Users\User>Mircrosoftwebdriver.exe
'Mircrosoftwebdriver.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

When you see the following response, then you know your path is set correctly for the Edge webdriver.

```
C:\Users\User>MicrosoftWebDriver.exe
[21:40:44.531] - Listening on http://localhost:17556/
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still relevant, however I was having the same problems even though it was in my path correctly. What I noticed was when I unpacked the driver after downloading from MS the name was all in lowercase 'microsoftwebdriver.exe'. Changed name in path so it was the same as the error message 'MicrosoftWebDriver.exe' and low and behold it now works.

Answer (score 0):

In my case. I have the correct path. My problem is the same as James'.
Rename the Edge browser drive from msedgedriver (all small letters) to MicrosoftWebDriver, then the problem should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect:
Rename the Edge browser drive from msedgedriver (all small letters) to MicrosoftWebDriver, then the problem should be solved.